# Assigning dummy variables to time series using if/else statement?

Tags: r

I have a column of dates, in yearmon format. I need to make a column based on them with a dummy variable, where it equals 1 for dates in 2008, and 0 otherwise. I'd do it the lazy way in excel, but need to do it using R. What are the easiest ways to make this sort of variable?

I've tried an if/else statement but can never get the syntax correct. The data file being referred to is called data, the yearmon column is called DATE, and the dummy variable being created will be called RECESSION.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
## generating some data
data <- data.frame(DATE =seq(as.Date('2008-01-01'), as.Date('2009-12-31'), 30))

## Creating the RECESSION variable 
data$RECESSION <- ifelse(grepl(pattern = '2008',  data$DATE), 1, 0)
```

```
print (data)

# DATE RECESSION
# 1  2008-01-01         1
# 2  2008-01-31         1
# 3  2008-03-01         1
# 4  2008-03-31         1
# 5  2008-04-30         1
# 6  2008-05-30         1
# 7  2008-06-29         1
# 8  2008-07-29         1
# 9  2008-08-28         1
# 10 2008-09-27         1
# 11 2008-10-27         1
# 12 2008-11-26         1
# 13 2008-12-26         1
# 14 2009-01-25         0
# 15 2009-02-24         0
# 16 2009-03-26         0
# 17 2009-04-25         0
# 18 2009-05-25         0
# 19 2009-06-24         0
# 20 2009-07-24         0
# 21 2009-08-23         0
# 22 2009-09-22         0
# 23 2009-10-22         0
# 24 2009-11-21         0
# 25 2009-12-21         0
```

Comment: Thank you, that does it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this without `ifelse`

```
data$RECESSION <- +(grepl(pattern = '2008',  data$DATE))
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(DATE =seq(as.Date('2008-01-01'), 
        as.Date('2009-12-31'), 30))
```